# Where did the dedicated "Recommended Videos" page moved on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

The latest update of YouTube doesn't seem to include the single-panel "Recommended Videos" - just a short list on the right-side panel.

Do you know if this recommended videos page is still available somewhere and if so, at what URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have not found the recommended videos but I have found the recommended topics which can be found here:

```
http://www.youtube.com/videos
```

Scroll to the bottom and you should see something like this:

[image: Recommended Video Via YouTube]

I assuming recommended topics is the same thing but maybe more general or just renamed.

Comment: /videos is a non-personalized global overview; and /topics is also not personalized -just the 3 selected topics you can choose from. What I'm really looking for is serendipity, preferably without much effort on my part (see old recommendation page)

Comment: @SilverDragon I don't think there is one anymore bro.

Comment: that is just sad :(

Comment: Yep it is. It's most likely changed to this topics thing now. I hope this answered your question though. I know it's not the answer you were looking for. @SilverDragon

Answer (score 0):

Update: Youtube has now added a dedicated recommended section:
http://www.youtube.com/recommended